# consolidating $.ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have several ajax call on my page and I want to consolidate them into one function.

For now I have this type of function in several places:

```
function AjaxCallOne () {

 //do something

 $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  url: TheURL,
  data: "{'TheData':'" + JsonData + "'}",
  dataType: "json",
  cache: "false",
  success:...
  error:...
 });
}
```

I want to write a single function that'll be used for all ajax calls like this:

```
function MyGeneralAjaxCall(TheData, TheURL, TheSuccessFunction, TheErrorFunction) {
  $.ajax({ .... });
}
```

My question is this: if I do that and the user send two ajax calls, almost simultaneously, to the point where the second ajax call is made before the returning data of the first call comes back, will the success or error functions trigger for the the correct call. I'm worried that the success function that'll be executed won't be for the proper ajax call if the user triggers a second call before the first one is returned.

Thanks.

Comment: You can set default values for the parameters to `$.ajax()` with [`$.ajaxSetup()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/). You don't need a wrapper function for this – unless for some reason you don't want to clobber the "factory" defaults.

Comment: @Inerdial, why is this not an answer?  you'd have my upvote.

Comment: @nathangonzalez Because it doesn't answer the OP's actual question. It's just a coincidence that he came to the question while doing something that might (or might not) be unnecessary.

Comment: @Inerdial, if someone asks you what the best way to kill someone is without being caught, you wouldn't try to tell them not to kill someone?

Comment: @nathangonzalez I don't think that analogy holds. (Besides the matter of degrees of severity. Nobody ever died of redundant code.) The OP's question is "what happens if two AJAX requests are made at the same time?", not "what's the best way to write an unnecessary wrapper function for `$.ajax()`?". You'd get the former if you deleted everything in the post except the last full paragraph, and it's a perfectly valid question that should be answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach will work as you expect.  Each success function, etc., that you pass in will be used individually by each associated AJAX call.  (All of your parameters will be kept together.)

Answer (score 0):

First, There's no single, global set of callbacks for ajax requests. Each ajax invocation gets it's own set of callbacks.

Secondly: $.ajax({...}) *is* your `MyGeneralAjaxCall`... if you are thinking you need a set of default options, a better way would be to set up a

```
var  defaultoptions = { type: "POST", ...}  //put default options, mimetypes, etc, here
```

(or something that returns that)  and then wherever needed do:

```
var myajaxoptions = $.extend({},defaultoptions,myoverrides); 
$.ajax(myajaxoptions);
```

That's much more extensible.  No need to make up "men in the middle".  Your approach will work, but I could easily see more than one  `MyGeneralAjaxCall` being created.  If you can manage not creating 5 or more methods like that `MyGeneralAjaxCall`, I suppose you'll be doing ok, but it could get nasty real quick.